# iPhone - insertSubview makes ObjectAlloc jump

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, delegates, subview

Whenever I add a new viewController my ObjectAlloc jumps up really high and never comes back down. Even after calling removeFromSuperview.  Is this normal?

```
if((UIButton *) sender == gameArcadeBtn) {
        GameArcade *gameArcadeController = [[GameArcade alloc] 
                              initWithNibName:@"GameArcade" bundle:nil]; 
        self.gameArcade = gameArcadeController; 
        [gameArcadeController release]; 
        [self.view insertSubview:gameArcadeController.view atIndex:1];
    }
```

Comment: Do I need to add [self dealloc] to the "back to menu button" instead of just [self.view removeFromSuperView]  when I am releasing the inserted subview?

Comment: You never, ever need a [self dealloc].  You should have a dealloc method that is never called explicitly by self, and in this method you need to have [super dealloc] as the last line.  Whoever created you is responsible for deallocing in most cases

Comment: Yeah I have a [self dealloc] with all my property retain items being released in there, but they never seem to be released when [self.view removeFromSuperview]; is called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instantiating a view always creates many objects.As long as this view is in memory or has not been autoreleased, the objects will remained alloced in memory.  Thus, to answer your question, this is normal.

It sounds like you are worried about memory usage and while it is important to watch the object allocs so that it doesn't get *too* it is more important to find your app leaks.

Some memory management tips:
1) do lazy loading.  Only load your views when the user asks for them, not all at the beginning of the app
2) remove everything that you possibly can when you dont need it anymore.  This means doing tons of work in viewWillAppear and viewDidDisappear
3) learn about @properties and how it relates to autoreleasing, and do not use properties for everything.
4) As appealing as it is, avoid autorelease and manually release objects when you dont need them anymore.

Comment: Yeah, only been programming for 2 months, in the process of building a game and after about 30 minutes of playing it sometimes crashes.  Instruments doesn't show a memory leak but the crash is caused from the overload of ObjectAlloc that builds up.

Comment: Everything with the retain property I know needs to be released and currently am in the process of making sure they are all released inside the dealloc.  How about when it comes to the assign property?

Comment: assign should not be released unless you are retaining it somewhere.

Comment: Majority of my IBOutlet stuff is retained,  UILabels, NSStrings, NSTimers, UIViews, UIButtons, UIImages....Basically everything but NSIntegers.  I am trying to make sure I released everything I retained.  Is there a purpose for this or am I creating more work for myself, should I just assign?

Comment: I think you are overthinking all this.  Here is the bottom line: retain only when you need something, and release it when you are done with it.  If you find yourself holding onto objects that you do not need anymore, then they are just taking up you app's ram.

Comment: Thanks for everything, yeah I know I am over thinking some things, production of the game was going so smooth and I expected it to be submitted by now but then I figured out that after 30mins to an hour of play it crashes, and now I am pulling my hair out.  I know that is a long time to play but I don't want a bad review of the app from someone, could lose money from potential buyers

Answer (score 0):

that's probably due to the fact that you're still retaining the view's controller in the class. try releasing that

Comment: [gameArcadeController release]; This is in my code just above the insertSubview.  Doesn't that release the controller?

Comment: Yeah but you assigned it to your "gameArcade" property, which retains it (or it should, because otherwise it will be invalid once the controller gets released). so you will need to release that property